# Want to improve my simple site/db backup script with auto removal of old backups

Tags: shell, scripting, cron, date

I have the following simple script for backing up my website files and db. The script is run each day via a cron job.

```
#!/bin/sh

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u username -p'password' dbname > /path/to/folder/backup/db-backup-$NOW.sql

gzip -f /path/to/folder/backup/db-backup-$NOW.sql

tar czf /path/to/folder/backup/web-backup-$NOW.tgz /path/to/folder/web/content/
```

It works great, but I don't want loads of old backups clogging my system. How can I modify the script to remove any backups older than a week when the script is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding something like this:

```
find -ctime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -v
```

`find -ctime +7 -print0` finds all files that were changed (the c) more than 7 days ago (+7) and sends that out as a `\0` separated string (`-print0`) which `xargs -0` sends to `rm -v` as arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Could you explain exactly what that code does? I am a but new to perl. I just want to understand what each part of that is doing.

Comment: @Robert Robb: will this explanation help?

Comment: `-ctime` is the time a file was changed not when it was created. The time a file was created is not saved.

Comment: @Dennis, right. It's `change time`, `modified time` and `access time`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

with GNU find, you can use `-delete`

```
find /path -type f -iname "*backup*gz" -mtime +7 -delete
```

or you can use `+;` in place of xargs.

```
find /path -type f -iname "*backup*gz" -mtime +7 -exec rm -f "{}" +;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give that a try too.